# ASP.NET MVC + JQuery Mobile event handlers

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I have ASP.NET MVC 3 + JQuery Mobile application with such structure of layout:

```
<body>
    <div class="page" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"></div>
        <div data-role="content" id="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The issue is, that event handlers binded to window stuck for several pages.

For example I have 2 pages: `"Index"` and `"About"`. In `"Index"` I bind some handler(say `console.log("index"))` on `$(window).click()` event. But when I go to `"About"` page - this handler is still active.

Is there any way to keep handlers only while appropriate page is active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made small research about this issue, but didn't find anything appropriate such issue.
So I've implemented solution for the discribed usecase with window events. It's creepy, but works.

In Layout:

1.Page div declaration:

```
<div class="page" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true"    id="@Request.RawUrl.GetHashCode()">
    ...
</div>
```

2.Scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bindEvents = [];
    $(document).bind('pagehide', function (event) {
        var hash = $(event.target).attr('id');
        $(window).unbind('.' + hash);
    });

    $(document).bind('pageshow', function (event) {
        var hash = $(event.target).attr('id');
        bindEvents[hash]();
    });
</script>
```

In pages:

1.Index:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var hashedIndex = '@Request.RawUrl.GetHashCode()';
if (!bindEvents.hasOwnProperty(hashedIndex)) {
    bindEvents[hashedIndex] = function() {
        $(window).bind('click.' + hashedIndex, function() {
            console.log('index');
        });
    };
};
</script>
```

2.About:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var hashedAbout = '@Request.RawUrl.GetHashCode()';
if (!bindEvents.hasOwnProperty(hashedAbout)){
    bindEvents[hashedAbout] = function () {
        $(window).bind('click.' + hashedAbout, function() {
            console.log('about');
        });
    };
};
</script>
```

And similar to other pages if needed.

In general case I agree with Gajotres: it's better to bind events to some inner containers to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use this kind of event binding with jQM:

```
$('#page').bind('click', function(e) {

});
```

With newer version of jQuery use .on( and .off( to bind/unbind event. $('#page') is your page.

This:

```
$(window).click()
```

will bind it to window, because jQM page is a single window event will fire every time.
You also need to worry about multiple event binding, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542166/1848600) you can find more info about this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to handle exactly window event(scrolling), so binding to some inner container is not possible in context of my application.

Comment: Then you need to find a way around it, jQM web app is a single window  app. What are you doing with window event(scrolling)?

Comment: Endless scrolling. I've tried plugins based on iscroll, but they are a bit buggy on some platforms. Now I'm looking for the way to implement endless scrolling without using window object - hope it will help with this issue.

Comment: Berker Yüceer: It is defined in Index.